# How to solve this SQL Server error I'm getting?

Tags: sql, sql-server

As you can see below I am trying to execute a stored procedure by passing the two parameters, I get error like

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
> Incorrect syntax near 'C:\SQL_Backup\Test.bak'.

Code:

```
EXEC Proc_RestoreSQL_Database ('C:\SQL_Backup\Test.bak','DMTest')
```

Stored procedure being executed:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_RestoreSQL_Database]
    @DISK nvarchar(1000),
    @DBName varchar(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Create DB with script(DMUtilityTest)
    CREATE DATABASE [@DBName]

    -- restore
    RESTORE DATABASE [@DBName] 
    FROM DISK = N'@DISK' 
END
```

Comment: You can't use variables to replace an object's name; SQL is a declarative language. You would have to use dynamic SQL and ***SAFELY*** inject the object's name. Also `DISK = N'@DISK'` isn't valid at all. Variable's within a literal string aren't escaped into the string.

Comment: But not with `CREATE DATABASE`, @GSerg, and for `RESTORE` the variable should not be wrapped in delimit identifiers.

Comment: Plus we have the fact that the above *assumes* that the files should be restored to the same location they were on the original host; which may well not be where they were when the database was created with the default locations. This seems like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info). Why not just create the database from the `RESTORE`? The `RESTORE` above would actually fail as you don't tell SQL Server to `REPLACE` the database you just created.

Comment: @Larnu how can we create database by restore? and i tryed removing DISK = N'@DISk' but my error remains the same.....Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
Incorrect syntax near 'C:\SQL_Backup\Test.bak'.

Comment: Also, as for the error, parameters for procedures aren't wrapped in parenthesis.

Comment: By default a database *is* created by `RESTORE`, @Amit . If you want to `RESTORE` over an existing database, you need to denote that the existing database be `REPLACE`d in the statement.

Comment: @Larnu i tryed something like this                                                                            exec Proc_RestoreSQL_Database ('C:\SQL_Backup\Test.bak','DMTest')
create procedure [dbo].[Proc_RestoreSQL_Database1]
--@DISK varchar(60),
--@DBName varchar(60),

AS
BEGIN
-- Create DB with script(DMUtilityTest)
 Create database ['@DBName']
RESTORE DATABASE ['@DBName'] FROM DISK = '@DISK' 
WITH REPLACE                                                                                                                        End

Comment: I don't know where you read that Procedure parameters need to be in parenthesis, @Amit , but where ever it was it was wrong.

Comment: @Laru exec Proc_RestoreSQL_Database ('C:\SQL_Backup\Test.bak','DMTest')    is this the right way?

Comment: No... Again, "parameters for procedures **aren't wrapped in parenthesis** [(`()`)]"...

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to `CREATE` the database if you are immediately going to restore it.

Just execute the restore directly. Do *not* wrap the database name parameter in `[]`, nor the filename parameter in quotes `''`, you *only* need this if you are embedding the actual name, not parameters.

You should also use more sensible parameter types

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_RestoreSQL_Database]
    @DISK nvarchar(255),
    @DBName sysname
AS
    RESTORE DATABASE @DBName
    FROM DISK = @DISK;

GO
```

This obviously assumes you are going to restore to the same location. You may want to pass new locations using `MOVE TO @newFile`

---

To execute it, again do not wrap in parenthesis `()`, just specify the parameter names

```sql
EXEC Proc_RestoreSQL_Database @DISK = 'C:\SQL_Backup\Test.bak', @DBName = 'DMTest';
```